# RewriteRule not working as expected?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to implement a front controller. So I want to redirect requests to index.php. Here is my .htaccess.

---

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect everything to the Front Controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^(css|images|files)/ index.php [NC,L]
```

---

Currently, if I visit the following url, it works:

```
http://devserver/myapp/
```

But, if I visit any url that does not resolve to index.php, for example `http://devserver/app/blog`,  Apache tells me that it cannot find index.php:

---

> The requested URL 
>   **/absolute/path/to/myapp/index.php**
>   was not found on this server.

---

But that path actually exists on my server, so I think what's happening is Apache is trying to access that url like a browser would - and it doesn't work because if I type in :
**/absolute/path/to/myapp/index.php** in my browser, it doesn't work. So, I decided to change the last line in my .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteRule !^(css|images|files)/ http://myapp.com/index.php [NC,L]
```

But it still doesn't work, because now when I check for `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` in my PHP code, it ***always*** resolves to `index.php` because Apache made a HTTP request.

Anyways, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, and I what I can do to make Apache redirect everything to index.php?

Thanks,

Comment: How about `RewriteRule !^(css|images|files)/ /index.php [NC,L]`

Comment: It says The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Do you have multiple .htaccess around? Is mod_rewrite enable?

Comment: No multiple htaccess, and yes, mod_rewrite is enabled. I think the problem is Apache is making a http request to an absolute path on my filesystem

Comment: Add this at top of htaccess:`RewriteBase /`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect everything to the Front Controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteRule !^(css|images|files)/ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Apache is still using the /absolute/path/to/index.php on my web server to find index.php, which doesn't resolve to anything in a browser :( Thanks though