# Apache rewrite behavior changes - depending on server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've got an apache headache, and I'm looking for some stackoverflow advil.

Here's the .htaccess.

```
php_flag display_errors off

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect everything to the Front COntroller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^(css|images|files)/ index.php [NC,L]
```

This is how it is treated on **Server A:**

1. Request is made to : `http://mysite.com/blog`
2. Request is routed to index.php
3. `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` resolves to `blog`

This is how it is treated on **Server <strike>Nightmare</strike> B:**

1. Request is made to : `http://mysite.com/blog`
2. Apache makes http call to `http://mysite.com/index.php`
3. `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` resolves to `index.php`

All I'm trying to do is reroute/write the request to index.php, without `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` being changed to `index.php`. In the above example, I would like `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` to resolve to `blog` on both Server A and Server B - but it's not working on Server B.

Could someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Kindly do not create multiple questions of a question you've already initiated [RewriteRule not working as expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277889/rewriterule-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: As a tangent, I prefer [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) for redirecting front-end controllers.